# Derangement with extra box

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, derangements

I was going through PnC questions and I came across this problem.

Four balls numbered $1,2,3,4$ are to be placed into five boxes numbered $1,2,3,4,5$ such that exactly one box remains empty and no ball goes to its own numbered box. The no. of ways is?

I worked out the problem in the following way.

Case 1: box 5 is not selected and thus total derangements $d_4=9$

Case 2: Any one of 4 boxes say box 1 is not selected $ C(4,1)$

case 2(a) ball 1 goes to box 5 then total derangements $d_3=2$

Case 2(b) ball 1 goes to either of other two boxes say box 2

Case 2(b)(i) ball 2 goes to 5 then $d_2=1$

Case 2(b)(ii) ball 2 doesn't go to box 5 then also  $d_2=1$

Thus, total number of ways $=9+C(4,1)\{2+2*2\}=33$

But none of the answer matches. Please help me identify error in the reasoning.

I got the error
Case 2(b) should be ball 1 goes to either of other three boxes say box 2

and
Case 2(b)(ii) ball 2 doesn't go to box 5 then also  $2*d_2=1$

So, finally it comes to $=9+C(4,1)\{2+3*(1+2)\}=53$

Comment: You can reduce this to counting derangements of four things and of five things.  You made a good start, as the possibilities if the fifth box remains empty corresponds to derangements of four things.  Now think about possibilities if the fifth box is not empty.

Answer (score 5):

Your mistake is in the last step.  Suppose box $1$ remains empty, and ball $1$ doesn't go into box $5$.  We can count these permutations by first deranging $4$ balls, and then transferring whichever ball ends up in box $1$ to box $5$.  There are $d_4=9$ such permutations, so the answer is $$9+4(2+9)=53$$

I didn't quite understand how you got $2\cdot2$ rather than $9$, so I can't be more specific about your mistake, sadly.

Another way to do the second part is to consider derangements of the $5$ balls, and then to remove ball $5$.  This gives the answer $$d_4+d_5=9+44=53$$

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a little late , but it may help you ,as well .I will use Inclusion-exclusion principle to solve the question.We know that there are $P(5,4)=120$ ways to place these balls into the boxes where there is one box empty.

Moreover , we do not want these situations such that ball $1$ is in box $1$ or ball $2$ is in box $2$ or ball $3$ is in box $3$ or ball $4$ is in box $4$. Lets call these situations by $A,B,C,D$ , respectively. We also do not want the situations such that $A \cap B , C \cap D ,B \cap C \cap D$ ,etc.. Then , we should subtract these unwanted situations from the total.

$\mathbf{\text{WORK:}}$ There are $C(4,2)=6$ cases like $A \cap B$ , $C(4,3)=4$ cases like $A \cap B \cap C$ , $C(4,4)=1$ cases like $A \cap B \cap C \cap D$

Then , $$120 - [(4 \times 4!) - (6 \times 3!) + (4 \times 2!) -1]= 120-67=53$$

$\mathbf{\text{NOTE:}}$ $A \cap B $ means the balls $1$ and $2$ are in their own boxes , the rest permutated randomly , $A \cap B \cap C$ means the balls $1$ and $2$ and $3$ are in their own boxes , the rest permutated randomly etc..